# Time trigger database updating

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table in SQL Server as following

```
ID | Name | ExpireTime         | CountLeft 
 1   test   11/11/2014 2:30         5
```

I want to update countLeft = 0 when ExpireTime = currenttime

Should i do this in the code behind or in SQL Server?

Comment: Uh, neither? Why can't the query just say `CountLeft = CASE WHEN ExpireTime < GETDATE() THEN 0 ELSE CountLeft END`? You can also wait to perform the update until the next time that row is read.

Comment: I want it to be updated as soon as time expires because other row depends on it

Comment: update it when ExpireTime <= currenttime

Comment: I am not sure when to call the query containing the above query

Comment: Another option would be a Sql agent job which runs every 1-5 mins and update any rows where your specified condition is true..... Or Simply Create a View which CountLeft 0 if the ExpireTime is <= GETDATE() ....

Comment: The problem with a job is that you can't run it every single second, so the data will not always be correct anyway.

Comment: every minute maybe but I think a View would be a better option

Answer (score 2):

This type of operation is not meant for databases. Triggers are event-based, not time-based. And while it maybe, possibly, kinda, sorta could be done via a SQL Agent Job that frequently polls the table, that process would have to hit every second in order for this to work and that might cause drag on the system and contention on the table.

However, there are technologies that are appropriate for such things. You should look into a cache server that allows for a lookup of a value where that value can be given an expiration date. Based on the design / needs of your app, you can write the entry to the DB at the same time that you write it to the cache server.

Check out:

- [memcached](http://memcached.org/)
- [redis](http://redis.io/)
- [Microsoft AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh351318.aspx)

Now, if you really, really, really, really, needed to handle this from SQL Server, you would have to:

1. Enable Snapshot Isolation (to reduce contention)
2. Create a stored procedure to do something like:
       UPDATE table
       SET CountLeft = 0
       WHERE ExpireTime < GETDATE();
3. Create 10 SQL Agent jobs where:

   - All 10 call this same stored procedure
   - All 10 are set to the minimum time interval of "every 10 seconds"
   - Each one is set to start at a different second: 00, 01, 02, ..., 09
4. Ask yourself why you didn't impliment this via a cache server ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can use a Service Broker conversation timer. Though I suspect that this is going to be a good implementation of a completely wrong design decision.