# Run script at 12 am at every time zone

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I'm trying to run a `.php` script on at 12 am (midnight) for every timezone.

**My goal:** I have a field in my database called `time_zone`. i need to send an email to that user in that "time zone" at 12 am.

i looked into cron jobs but i don't think it works well with timezones. is there any other way to achieve this?

EDIT: I did think about running the script every 30 min because some timezones are 30 min apart but that doesn't seem like a good solution because i wouldn't know how to calculate in which time zone it is 12:00 am.

Comment: If you want to run it at midnight in every timezone, then you should just run it once every hour since it's always midnight in some timezone.

Comment: You need to give more information. Is the script running centrally on a server, or is it running locally on a number of machines that need to identify their own time zones?

Comment: @ebraley and also on some half-hours and quarter-hours. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets

Comment: the script will be run on one server

Comment: Why do you need to know which timezone is 12am? What does the script do? Perhaps you should share a little more about what do you intend to do.

Comment: @Terry edited the post

Comment: It's a lot like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961104/run-cron-job-at-12-am-in-every-time-zone) from yesterday. How about the suggestion from [this comment on that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961104/run-cron-job-at-12-am-in-every-time-zone#comment76897916_44961104)?

Comment: @Don'tPanic does that bump it?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Don'tPanic well if i comment on an old question, how does that make it appear at the top where people can see it?

Comment: No, commenting on it won't make it appear at the top again.

Comment: @Don'tPanic ok, sorry im new to this but how would the question get attention so people can try to answer?

Comment: @JasonBale see https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266338/how-can-i-improve-my-questions-or-how-to-get-more-attention-for-my-questions ,and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/getting-attention-for-unanswered-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an array of all time-zones and compare from that. If that exists in the array you can send the email. It's not perfect, but it should do the job.

Comment: how so? example?

Comment: $array = array('TZ_1', 'TZ_2', 'TZ_3', ...)

foreach($timezone in $array){
     $cur_time = time() // get current time with required format

    If array contains the $timezone
        send the email
}

Comment: but how would you calculate the time? for example, how would you see which time zone is 12:00 am so i can run the script?

Comment: php is a server side language... so when you'll request a page, it'll show that. One way is that you could make a page, and do an AJAX call on it, and as long as the page is there,, the ajax call will continuously check the time by above logic and send email from there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980282/time-trigger-database-updating